# SQL using Top 5 Results as a filter

Tags: sql, filter, subquery, common-table-expression

I need to find out the SQL mechanism to use the 5 categories that I have calculated with a CTE to be able to filter my overall results.  When I "join" with a comma:  from table,cte the reults multiply.  I don't really have a field to do a proper join because of the count calculation in the cte.

I feel like it should be a subquery in the where statement, but I have 5 results and I think it only works with 1 result.

I have tried (to the best of my ability) cte, various subqueries, having, exists

Working CTE:

```
DECLARE @END VARCHAR(25)='2021-04-04 23:59:59.000'  --Sunday

DECLARE @START DATEtime = DATEADD(DD,-364,@END)

;With CTE as (

Select Top 5

          TIER_3 

         ,COUNT(INCIDENT_NUMBER) AS CTE_Count    

    FROM vIncidentTickets

   WHERE LAST_RESOLVED_DATE between @START and @END

     AND GROUP = 'Cell'

     AND COMPANY = 'HQ'

     AND ORGANIZATION = 'CSS'

GROUP BY TIER_3

ORDER BY COUNT(INCIDENT_NUMBER) DESC
)
```

--The select portion doesn't provide correct results

```
Select    
          INCIDENT_NUMBER

         ,CTE.TIER_3 

    FROM vIncidentTickets,CTE

   WHERE LAST_RESOLVED_DATE between @START and @END

     AND GROUP = 'Cell'

     AND COMPANY = 'HQ'

     AND ORGANIZATION = 'CSS'
```

I want the CTE results to filter the Select query.

Answer (score 0):

***DON'T*** join using a comma. The standard for using `JOIN` keywords is nearly 30 years old, get used to it and use it.

By using `INNER JOIN` in particular, it becomes clear that you've not included any conditions to relate the two tables (no join predicate).

Try this instead...

```
Select    
      v.INCIDENT_NUMBER
     ,CTE.TIER_3 
FROM
    vIncidentTickets   AS v
INNER JOIN
    CTE
        ON CTE.TIER_3 = v.TIER_3
WHERE
     v.LAST_RESOLVED_DATE between @START and @END
 AND v.GROUP = 'Cell'
 AND v.COMPANY = 'HQ'
 AND v.ORGANIZATION = 'CSS'
```

(Your original query was effectively using `CROSS JOIN`.)